# Can't install programs nor change system settings because admin password is not recognized on Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, install, settings

I can't install programs nor change system settings. I have admin privileges and I can successfully login into my account. I can even perform admin operations in terminal using `sudo` command.

But, when I try to install new software and enter the admin password, it always give me an "incorrect password" message.

Comment: Neither the ability to login, nor sudo access, are indicative of admin privileges. Does the Users panel in System Preferences list that you are an Admin?

Comment: Yes, it does. In fact, this suddenly happened, I have always had admin privileges.

Comment: What do you mean by "the admin password"? The password you need is the account password. Can you log into your account that has admin privileges? That is the password you need, not some separate "admin" password.

Comment: It's my account password, I am the only user. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done any of the obvious fixes yet?

- repair file system
- repair permissions
- check keyboard encoding when prompted for password entry
- ...

Have you looked into the `system.log` for possible hints?

Comment: Thanks! I've done #1 an #2. Then I change my keyboard encoding and worked! I don't know why this happened, in the console or text editor I have no problem typing my password with the current encoding.